# Is it possible to know the type of return value of a function in Go?

Tags: go

For example, I want to do something like this,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var f func(int) int
    v := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    fmt.Println(v.ReturnType() == reflect.TypeOf(1)) // => true
}
```

`ReturnType` method doesn't exist in reflect package.
My question is, can I implement such a function without using `cgo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using `reflect.ValueOf(f)` try `reflect.TypeOf(f)`. The `Type` type has two relevant methods named `NumOut` and `Out(int)`. To get the types of all return values in order, you can use the following loop

```
typ := reflect.TypeOf(f)

for i := 0; i < typ.NumOut(); i++ {
    returnType := typ.Out(i)
    // do something with returnType
}
```

If you're certain your function only has one return value, you can always get it with `Out(0)`, the standard disclaimers about making sure your input is correct apply.